# What parameters can be used in ShellExec or Exec function in Inno Setup when executing 3rd party installer?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, execute, shellexecute

I am quite new to Inno Setup. I am currently compiling an installer for my .exe and I have come to know that `ShellExec` and `Exec` (File Functions) allows me execute 3rd-party installers.

May I know what are the available value(s) or string(s) for 'Params' input of both these functions? At the moment, I only know `/S` is for silent install (hide the 3rd-party install window). Any resource(s)/cheatlists/cheatsheet(s) on this is greatly appreciated. I am not sure where to refer to on this because their documentation on those two File Functions did not explain on it.

Inno Setup Documentation (File Functions): https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptfunctions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "params" are specific to the third-party installers. You didn't tell us anything about them.

Though the `/S` is used by NSIS-made installers. For NSIS commandline parameters, see:
https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Chapter3.html#installerusagecommon

Though it's quite possible that even other installers use `/S`.

In general running an installer (or any program) with `/?` (or `-?`, `/h`, `/help`, etc) should give you commandline help.